# Commutation preserving operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be unital $C$*-algebras and let $T\colon A\to B$ be a bounded linear bijection that preserves commuting elements, i.e., $ab=ba$ implies $TaTb=TbTa$. Does $T^{**}$ then also preserve commuting elements?

An approach to answer this question would be to weak*-approximate commuting elements in $A^{**}$ by commuting elements of $A$, but by [Commuting nets for commuting projections](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/181222/commuting-nets-for-commuting-projections) this already seems to fail for projections.